# Oracle SQL Select Query

Tags: sql

existing Query:

Query -1 :

```
select count(unique clientMacAddress) uniqueClients 
from ClientSessionInfo ClientSessionInfo 
where ClientSessionInfo.sessionStartTime >= 1383206920000 and ClientSessionInfo.sessionStartTime <= 1383210520000
```

Columns in the table:

```
a. SessionStartTime

b. clientMacAddress

c. ConnectionType
```

Requirement :

show the total no.Of unique Wired Clients  and  total no of unique wireless clients along with total no.Of Unique Clients

if connectionType = 0, then it is connectionType is 'Wireless'
if connectionType = 1, then it is connectionType is 'Wired'

Solution :
Query -1 will return the total no of unique clients.

Write one more query (Query-2)  to retrieve the wireless clients. 
Query -2:

```
select count(unique clientMacAddress) uniqueClients 
from ClientSessionInfo ClientSessionInfo 
where ClientSessionInfo.sessionStartTime >= 1383206920000 and ClientSessionInfo.sessionStartTime <= 1383210520000  and connectionType = 0
```

Based on the output of Query -1 and Query -2, wired clients can be drived.

Instead of writing Query -2, is there any way to modify the query -1 to retrieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Using group by clause to differentiate group by clause

```
select connectionType, count(distinct clientMacAddress)
from ClientSessionInfo csi
where csi.sessionStartTime >= 1383206920000 and csi.sessionStartTime <=1383210520000
group by connectionType
```